# Buttons in shapes other than rectangles

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Is it possible to create buttons in shapes other than rectangles (or rounded rectangles).  Could you, for instance, create a button in the shape of a state on a map?  Would clicking anywhere in the shape cause a MouseEvent to be broadcast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create such buttons by extending JButton and calling `setContentAreaFilled(false);`
 in the constructor. Then you can paint whatever you like in the overridden `paintComponent()` method. Also you need to override the `contains()` method of `JComponent` to provide desired mouse hit-test. In this method you can call polygon's (the one used for drawing the button) `contains()` method.

Comment: In Swing you should usually override paintComponent, not paint

Comment: Yes overriding paintComponent() is the recommended way to go, I will update my answer thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, render your map using instances of classes that implement the `Shape` interface, such as `Polygon`. Any of the supported `contains()` methods will work.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample from the JDC Tech Tips:

http://web.mit.edu/java/JDCNewsletter/JDC-TECH8-99